# c# convert encoding 1252 to 1251

Tags: c#, encoding

Trying to convert text in encoding cp 1252 to cp 1251. 
This code workds great.

```
var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
textBox2.Text = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(bytes);
```

But with big files it not so easy. So i try to using file stream. If i try to read file - > convert to bytes - > write . And it is does not work. Adding Encodig.GetEncoding(1252) to read and Encoding.GetEncoding(1251) to write does not help.

```
 string file_data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
 var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(file_data);
 string file_data_in_1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(bytes);
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_1251", file_data_in_1251);
```

If i read file in bytes...

```
byte[] allData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
string file_data_in_1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(allData);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_1251", file_data_in_1251, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```

It works but not for all files. First code works with all files.

I compare bytes data from text to bytes and file to bytes and its different!

Text

```
[0] 32  byte
[1] 60  byte
[2] 32  byte
[3] 116 byte
[4] 97  byte
[5] 103 byte
[6] 32  byte
[7] 107 byte
[8] 32  byte
[9] 61  byte
```

File

```
[0] 32  byte
[1] 60  byte
[2] 116 byte
[3] 97  byte
[4] 103 byte
[5] 32  byte
[6] 107 byte
[7] 61  byte
[8] 39  byte
[9] 78  byte
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: ReadAllText has an overload that takes an encoding, use that instead.

Comment: Open the file with Notepad.  Then use SaveAs.  On the Dialog box there is an encoding box.   Check the encoding box to see what encoding is being used.

Answer (score 1):

A `string` in memory is stored as `UTF16`, so your program is currently performing the following steps:

```
// let C# guess the encoding of the file and convert to UTF16
string file_data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

// get a byte array of that string in 1252 encoding
var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(file_data);

// pretend the 1252 encoded data is actually 1251 encoded and convert to UTF16
string file_data_in_1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(bytes);

// let C# decide what encoding to use when writing the file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_1251", file_data_in_1251);
```

As Igor suggested, you can supply the encoding to the `ReadAllText` method to tell C# what the file is currently encoded as, and also to `WriteAllText` to indicate what encoding to write.

So the following would do the trick:

```
string file_data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_1251", file_data, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```

I tried the following code in a console application to test this:

```
string t = "háéó < tag k =";
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\1.tmp", t, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
string read = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\1.tmp", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\2.tmp", read, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```

Result file contains:

> haeo < tag k =

Comment: I trying this and it doesnt help. Result file contains ???? instead of text.

Comment: @Дмитрий I got too confident there, typing an answer without trying the code :) will do now

Comment: @Дмитрий Are you sure the source file is 1252 encoded?

Answer (score 0):

One of this options will work. Option 1 read all bytes:

```
byte[] allData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
string file_data_in_1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(allData);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_1251", file_data_in_1251, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```

Option 2 . Read file by lines -> store in array -> concat array into string -> string into bytes -> bytes into string with need encoding.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
string line;
string lin2;
int counter = 0;

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    counter++;
}
file.Close();

System.IO.StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);

string[] file_by_lines = new string[counter+5];

for(int i =0; i < counter; i++)
{
    lin2 = file2.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lin2))
    {
        file_by_lines[i] = lin2;
    }
}
file2.Close();

string file_by_line = string.Concat(file_by_lines);

var b = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(file_by_line);
string s = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(b);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_1251_variant1", s, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```